# Mac app installed in unknown place on developer's machine

Tags: macos, installation, electron-builder

I'm developing a Mac Electron-based app. When I install the electron-builder generated pkg on Macs others than my development machine, it is installed either globally in the `/Applications` folder, or locally for the user - based on the user's choice during installation. It also appears properly in the Launch Pad.

However, on my development machine, when I install the app from the same pkg, it is not installed there. It is installed somewhere else - and I'm not sure where. It may be the last place where I compiled the app, but I am uncertain. Launch Pad is also uncertain, and most of the times the app does not appear there after installation.

It is obvious the Mac is keeping track of a default installation folder for each application, which for some reason overrides the user selection during installation.

Where is this taking place, and how can I reset it so the Mac app is installed where it should? It makes testing a real pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either search for the app using Spotlight search

`⌘` + `Space-bar`

And then hold they command key after you select your app int the spotlight seach.
A bar with the location of the file will appear at the bottom of the spotlight search window.

[Path for the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqAFI.png)

Or you could search for it using the `find` command on terminal.

`find / -name YourApp.app`